# Rename field parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here's teh pbix file https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amd7BXzYs7AVlm0j7IBWB7EZWKIM?e=LTrZMe

I use field parameter

```
Slice by = {
    ("Brand", NAMEOF('Product'[Brand]), 0),
    ("Category", NAMEOF('Product'[Category]), 1),
    ("Color", NAMEOF('Product'[Color]), 2),
    ("Continent", NAMEOF('Customer'[Continent]), 3),
    ("Country", NAMEOF('Customer'[Country]), 4)
}
```

[image]

I add a slicer Month-year

[image]

I'd like when I select for the slicer monthyear for example feb 2020, I'd like that in the matrix Brand and category will be renamed as Brand feb 2020 and category feb 2020, is there a way to do it please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power BI will not let you dynamically change the name of a label in a column.  You could either include the `year month` as a column as you would in a matrix table.

Or you could add a measure that shows the selected value and put that in a card or multi card visual above the table.  The measure would be defined like this:

```
TimeSelectionLabel = 
IF ( HASONEVALUE ( Date[Month] ), SELECTEDVALUE ( Date[Month] ), "" )
```